# How do I store tiled images as tif efficiently using Python

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff

I am developing an application that produces very large (up to gigapixel) images consisting of individual 4-channel 16 bit tiles. I am currently creating a folder per image and then just writing a bunch of separate files into this folder,each representing a "tile". The tiles are of equal size (3300x2700) but their alignment isn't perfectly uniform and though they observe a grid-like arrangement their specific location has minute variation along both the X and Y axis, I would like to store them in a format that is aware of such offsets and allows me to add it to the metadata. I.e. I would like a file format format comparable to layers in photoshop or GIMP. Each layer consisting of image data and it's placement within the 'canvas' of the large image. Obviously, given the size of the image, I would also like to avoid to having to store incredible amounts of black/transparent pixels bloating the file size. What I would like to end up with is a file that displays the image correctly, but also gives me the ability to recover the individual tiles that form it.

I vaguely recall, that Hugin(more specifically it's `PTStitcher` i.e. the part of the program that does image registrations and alignment) actually outputs a format consisting of multiple "layers" in a tif-file and I have my eye on the python `tifffile` project. Despite repeated efforts of looking for a snippet of code that achieves this or even something similar, I haven't been able to find any leads. Possibly for lack of the right terminology to research this problem with....

An ideal solution would be compatible with GIMP, so that I can open the file in GIMP and have individual, pre-aligned layers. But this is not a must...

I attached an image that illustrates what the tiles look like, arranged in a grid, though my use case would obviously see these tiles overlap in reality

[image: Example image grid]

Any suggestions are welcome

I have researched the matter and found formats such as MicroManager Indexmap or geospatial formats, but no code snippet that shows how to encode this information using the `tifffile` library, though I suspect it is possible.

Comment: TIFF stores tiled images if the tiles form a regular grid. I haven’t seen what Hugin does, maybe it stores each tile as a separate directory, and somehow stores the offset for each. I don’t know if there’s standard software that displays that properly.

Comment: There are custom file formats that do this though. The 3DHistech scanners store tiles as JPEG, concatenate in larger binary files stored together in a directory, and include an index file with information for how to render them. Of course such a solution requires a custom viewer, and is hard to integrate into other data flows. It is much better to crop/patch the tiles to make them into a regular grid, then store as a regular tiled TIFF file. Lots of software will be able to read those.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I actually investigated my claim re: Hugin some more. Turns out it just stores compressed tifs of equal dimension(the size of the panorama) with only the relevant part containing any data. I think I will store the data as a regular grid with no regard for the overlapping portions' alignment. Keeping every single pixel for future processing is more important to me than proper viewing. A snippet that stores such a regular grid would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, standard TIFF does not support non-aligned "tiles", and tiles must all be the same shape with width and height divisible by 16. It should be possible to use Adobe's layered TIFF format and store the "tiles" as layers. I don't think GIMP supports that format though. You can write layered TIFF with tifffile and the [psdtags](https://pypi.org/project/psdtags) library. The Zeiss CZI format should also be capable. Also check the [GDAL Virtual Format](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html) and the [Image.sc forum](https://forum.image.sc/) for MicroManager support.

Comment: @cgohlke Thank you for chiming in, having the input from the author of the lib in question sure is valuable. I think  I will stick to a folder of files after all, store the metadata and then write a wrapper that derives an RGB image for viewing.  I made my move away from OpenCV's imwrite and towards tifffile and I am having trouble dealing with the 4th channel(alpha) and can't find an example of how to write it along with the RGB data(analogous to OpenCV's IMWRITE_UNGHANGED). May I suggest adding such an example to the guide

Comment: I got that wrong, the OpenCV refers to reading such files, not writing them. In any case OpenCV is able to write 4 channel tif files